# How to call a python class function from another file

Tags: python

I have this class in my parser.py file

```
class HostInfo(object):
def __init__(self, host_id):
    self.osclass = []
    self.osmatch = []
    self.osfingerprint = []
    self.portused = []
    self.ports = []
    self.extraports = []
    self.tcpsequence = {}
    self.hostnames = []
    self.tcptssequence = {}
    self.ipidsequence = {}
    self.trace = {'port': '', 'proto': '', 'hop': []}
    self.status = {}
    self.address = []
    self.hostscript = []

    # Umit extension
    self.id = host_id
    self.comment = ''

    # XXX this structure it not being used yet.
    self.nmap_host = {
            'status': {'state': '', 'reason': ''},
            'smurf': {'responses': ''},
            'times': {'to': '', 'srtt': '', 'rttvar': ''},
            'hostscript': [],
            'distance': {'value': ''},
            'trace': {'port': '', 'proto': '', 'hop': []},
            'address': [],
            'hostnames': [],
            'ports': [],
            'uptime': {'seconds': '', 'lastboot': ''},
            'tcpsequence': {'index': '', 'values': '', 'class': ''},
            'tcptssequence': {'values': '', 'class': ''},
            'ipidsequence': {'values': '', 'class': ''},
            'os': {}
            }
```

after that it defined a function which trying to find an host id from a xml file

```
def get_id(self):
    try:
        return self._id
    except AttributeError:
        raise Exception("Id is not set yet.")

def set_id(self, host_id):
    try:
        self._id = int(host_id)
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        raise Exception("Invalid id! It must represent an integer, "
                "received %r" % host_id)
```

Now i want to use call this `get_id` function from an another file.I tried so many time but it shows an error i.e. module can't be import

Comment: Does parser.py compile?  Your indentation - as posted (please fix) - is incorrect, which would keep it from importing.

Comment: /have you imported from that file? Suppose `get_id` is in a file called A.py. In your main file, you should do `from A import get_id`

Comment: Don't use getter and setters in python code. It's considered bad practice. Use [`property()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
from parser import HostInfo

obj = HostInfo(<whatever host_id you need here>)
obj.get_id
```

this is the way, how are you actually doing it?

Comment: Yeh, but now i am confused about that how to paas the argument to obj.get_id function?

Comment: @sharda PAL: if get_id is a method of your HostInfo class, then self = the instance of that class. So, in my example, self is "obj". I have a question for you: what's that object parameter? in that code you're not using it anywhere, so i guess the best definition for your class is '' class HostInfo: ''. You don't need to pass self to get_id, it's implicit.